# False conflict in glibc version?

Tags: python3

Trying to install torch over conda, on Ubuntu 18.04, I get:

```
Package pytorch-mutex conflicts for:
cpuonly -> pytorch-mutex==1.0=cpu
torchvision -> pytorch-mutex==1.0[build='cuda|cpu']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.27=0
  - pytorch==1.4 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - torchvision -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
  - torchvision -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.27
```

It seems the glibc version (2.27) does match all listed constraints.  What conflict is the installation talking about?

Comment: Not maybe a fix to your problem but it might be. Ubuntu 18.04 goes EOL at the end of May so now might be a good time to upgrade. The software you are install may work well on a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @David this is not a personal computer and the OS is not under my control

Comment: Then pass this on to whom ever may care.